Failed installing chemml due to module dependency conflict
I'm installing chemml as described in https://github.com/hachmannlab/chemml on MacOS 13.1 / Anaconda 1.12.3
conda create --name chemml_env python=3.8
source activate chemml_env
conda install -c conda-forge openbabel rdkit nb_conda_kernels python-graphviz
pip install chemml

Installation reports dependency conflict:
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
sqlalchemy 2.0.32 requires typing-extensions>=4.6.0, but you have typing-extensions 4.5.0 which is incompatible.

When forcing typing-extensions to version 4.12.2 to address the dependency conflict, I get dependency conflict with tensorflow which requires typing-extensions<4.6.0
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts. tensorflow 2.13.1 requires typing-extensions<4.6.0,>=3.6.6, but you have typing-extensions 4.12.2 which is incompatible.

Should I try to install a different version of tensorflow?
